# "TypeError: <lambda>() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given" Lambda expression in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I write a simple lambda function to generate a random list of booleans with the following code:

```
randBinList = lambda n: [random()<0.5 for _ in range(n)]
```

This function works perfect, for example:

```
>>> randBinList(100)
[False, False, True, False, False, True, True, False, True, False, False, False, False, True, False, True, False, False, False, False, False, False, True, False, True, True, True, False, False, True, True, False, False, False, False, True, False, True, False, True, False, False, True, False, False, False, True, False, True, False, False, False, False, True, True, True, True, False, True, True, True, True, False, True, True, True, True, False, False, True, True, False, True, False, True, False, True, True, False, False, False, False, True, True, False, False, False, False, True, False, False, True, True, True, False, True, False, True, False, False]
```

However, when I tried to add this function to a new class I'm working on I received the following error:

```
return self.randBinList(num_of_features)
TypeError: <lambda>() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

I do not know why it says that tow arguments were given? Here is the code of my class.  Thanks for your help.

```
import sys, csv, os, subprocess, time
from collections import deque, defaultdict
import random 
from typing import List
    class ScriptFeatures():
        randBinList = lambda n: [random()<0.5 for _ in range(n)]

        def get_random_individual (self):
            num_of_features = len(self.d)
            return self.randBinList(100)
```

Comment: You are calling your lambda as a method so an implicit `self` parameter is being passed, in a way the actual call will be something like `self.randBinList(self,100)`

Comment: Note that the import is incorrect.  it should be :"from random import random"

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This example reproduces your error.

```
import numpy as np

class A(object):
    rand_bin_list = lambda n: [np.random.random() < 0.5 for _ in range(n)]

    def __init__(self):
        print(self.rand_bin_list(5))
```

The problem here is that when you construct a function within a class, and call it prefixed with `self.` you need to include self as the first argument. So you can either add `self` as an argument, or you can define the function in the `__init__`. So either

```
class A(object):
    rand_bin_list = lambda self, n: [np.random.random() < 0.5 for _ in range(n)]

    def __init__(self):
        print(self.rand_bin_list(5))
```

or

```
class A(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.rand_bin_list = lambda n: [np.random.random() < 0.5 for _ in range(n)]
        print(self.rand_bin_list(5))
```

Comment: Thanks too much for the explanation.  I'm learning how to use OO in python.  I come from a Java Background and still learning the new syntaxis of python.

Comment: Is there any special reason to use numpy, instead of the standard random module?

Comment: @Rodrigo No, not really.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to make it work is to call the lambda as a class method, rather than an object method. Here is user2653663 's example with the fix:

```py
import numpy as np

class A(object):
    rand_bin_list = lambda n: [np.random.random() < 0.5 for _ in range(n)]

    def __init__(self):
        print(self.__class__.rand_bin_list(5))
```

The use of `__class__` in the last line makes it work, because it avoids calling `rand_bin_list()` as a member of `self`.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the answer above, I redefined `randBinList` as a local function inside the method `get_random_individual`, which also works.

```
from random import random
from typing import List

class ScriptFeatures():

    def get_random_individual (self):
        randBinList = lambda n: [random() < 0.5 for _ in range(n)]
        num_of_features = len(self.d)
        individual = randBinList(num_of_features)
        return  individual
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to override the `on_checkbox_Active` callback.

Register to the callback ->

```
self.testCheckBox.bind(active= self.on_checkbox_Active)
```

override  ->

```
def on_checkbox_Active(self,checkboxInstance, isActive):
                     print('test CheckBox')
```

Comment: I've edited your answer to improve the formatting. Can you review to both ensure it is as you expect, but also to learn how to format your code in the future?